# What is highest coefficient ofthe polynomial $t(t+1)(t+2) \cdots (t+n)$ for arbitrary $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions

How to find the coefficient of in the polynomial

$t(t+1)(t+2) \cdots (t+n)$ for arbitrary $n$

?

According to me it should be the sum of the products of the numbers from $1,2,\cdots,n$ taking $k$ at a time i.e. it is a sum of $n \choose k$ products. Now if this is true then how do I find out the highest coefficient in that expansion?I feel real trouble in that case.I take quite a few examples and observe that the coefficient of $t^2$ is the highest among all other if $n \geq 2$.But I can't prove it in general.

Please help me in proving this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Up to a sign, these are the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number)

Comment: For $7 \le n \le 23$, the coefficient for $t^3$ is largest. At $n = 24$, the coefficient for $t^4$ takes over. not sure when will $t^5$ takes over.

Comment: we would need to know an (asymptotic) interpolating function for the Stirling 1 numbers in order to answer to your question. However it is sure that the max. is drifting to $\infty$ at the increasing of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a missing index in here, but roughly this is:

$$
a_{k}=t^k \sum_{i=1}^{(n \ n+1-k)}\prod_{j \text{ in } C_i(n,n+1-k)} j
$$

$C(n,k)$ is the set of all combinations of the integers from 1 to $n$, taking $k$ at each time, and $C_i$ is its $i$th element. The size of $C(n,k)$ is the binomial coefficient $(n \ k)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

$$
C(n,0)=\{\}\\
C(n,1)=\{\{1\},...,\{n\}\}\\
C(n,2)=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},...,\{n-2,n\},\{n-1,n\}\}\\
...\\
C(n,n-1)=\{\{2,...n\},\{1,3,...,n\},\{1,...,n-2,n\},\{1,...,n-1\}\}\\
C(n,n)=\{\{1,...n\}\}\\
C(n,n+1)=\{\}\\
$$

Comment: What would be the highest coefficient in that expansion?

Comment: $t^{n+1}+t^{n}\sum_{i=1}^ni+...+t\prod_{j=1}^nj$

Comment: Yeah I know that. But can you say that which coefficient is the largest?I guess it is the coefficent of $t^2$?Can you make it clear to me?I just draw this conclusion by taking quite a few examples.But that doesn't guarantee that the generalised result is true.Please help me in understanding it much clearly.

Comment: Can I use the fact that: $ \left[{n+1\atop k}\right] = n \left[{n\atop k}\right] + \left[{n\atop k-1}\right]$?

Comment: If you have a binomial coefficient, yes. But i dont see any.......

Answer (score 1):

So we have that
$$
t\left( {t + 1} \right) \cdots \left( {t + n} \right) = t^{\,\overline {\,n + 1\,} } 
$$
and
$$
t^{\,\overline {\,n + 1\,} }  = \sum\limits_{\,\left( {1\, \leqslant } \right)\,k\,\left( { \leqslant \,n + 1} \right)} {\left[ \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right]t^{\,k} } 
$$

Now
$$
P(k;\,q) = {1 \over {q!}}\left[ \matrix{
  q \cr 
  k \cr}  \right]
$$
is a discrete Probability distribution
(see for instance [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151206))
whose raw first and second moment are
$$
\eqalign{
  & E\left[ k \right] = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,g\,\left( { \le \,q} \right)} {{k \over {q!}}\left[ \matrix{
  q \cr 
  k \cr}  \right]}  = H(q) = \gamma  + \psi (q + 1)  \cr 
  & E\left[ {k^{\,2} } \right] = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k} {{{k^{\,2} } \over {q!}}\left[ \matrix{
  q \cr 
  k \cr}  \right] = } \left( {H_{\,q} ^2  + H_{\,q}  - {{\pi ^2 } \over 6} + \psi ^{\left( 1 \right)} \left( {q + 1} \right)} \right) \cr} 
$$

Your question concerns the mode of $\left[ \matrix{  q \cr   k \cr}  \right]$  which coincides with that of $P(k;\,q)$, 
but I could not find sufficient information on line about this distribution and its characteristics.

Plotting some examples of $P(k;\,q)$ it comes out that it has quite a peaked and symmetric shape concentrated in the lower values of $k$
and that the mode remains very close to the mean.
So ${\rm mode}\,P(k;q) \approx H(q)$.

If you need a more analytical result, then you can try and interpolate $P(k;\,q)$ by a continuous function, 
which has a closed expression for the mode.