# Traffic Flow problem space time diagram question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

> Traffic with constant density, $\rho_0$, is stopped by a red light at $x=0$. If $v(\rho)=1-\rho$, calculate what happends behind the light.

Unfortunately the main focus of this example in my notes wasn't on the space-time diagram so they provide the graph https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgA65.jpg  without much explanation except for "Characteristics are given by $x=(1-2\rho)t+s$" and "Characteristics always intersect at $x=0$, $t=0$ for $0<\rho_0<1$". (Then after dealing with the shock, the graph https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHdSh.jpg. The shock isn't really the focus of my question though because I'm not far into the problem when it comes to my understanding of it)

What I'm not understanding is how the characteristics I'm seeing in the first graph are coming from $x=(1-2\rho)t+s$. For instance for $x<0$ the graph suggests the characteristics have positive gradient but if $\rho_0=\frac{3}{4}$ we have $x=-\frac{1}{2}t+s$ so $\frac{dt}{dx}=-2$ which is negative.

EDIT: Also, where does $\rho=1$ come from?

If someone could please answer my question I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I let someone else to give you a comprehensive answer, but I can say you what I'm trying. The pde to solve is $$\rho_t+(1-2\rho)\rho_x=0$$. The boundary conditions are $\rho(x,0)=\rho_0$ for $x\lt0$ and $\rho(x,t)=0$ for $x\gt0$. The boundary conditions are incompatible for a continuous function, so, you have to look for how to patch the solutions with one bc and with the other (this is why you have two families of intersecting lines in the first picture) and it's possible by means the shockwave drawn in the second picture. Further, $\rho=1$ is actually $\rho(0,t)=1$ as the cars stop at $x=0$!

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense, thank you! Do you know what the gradient of the characteristics are for $x<0$?

Comment: More. For this pde, homogeneous, etc. the function ($\rho$ in this case) is constant along the characteristics. So, we have $\rho=\rho_0$ for one patch and $\rho=1$ for the other.

Comment: Okay so does that mean that the characteristics for $x<0$ are governed by $x=(1-2\rho_0)t+s$?

Comment: The second picture is good to understand it all. The slope changes sign at the shockwave. And partially no, the lines before the shockwave are indeed $x=(1-2\rho_0)t+s$ but after it are $x=-t+s$. Try to patch these two families for different $s$. This draws the shockwave.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So becaue the characteristics before the shockwave have a positive gradient then that would suggest $1-2\rho_0>0 \Rightarrow \rho_0<\frac{1}{2}$. So does that mean we can't have $\rho_0=\frac{3}{4}$ because $1-2(\frac{3}{4})=-\frac{1}{2}$ which is negative? This is my last question I promise

Comment: I am sorry, but it is because the point about the gradient I cannot give you the comprehensive answer I said before. I don't get the point about that and, although I think it's not fundamental, I have not an answer for sure. And don't worry about how many questions, the limit is only the understanding about the question :). Unfortunatelly, I reached it.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I gave here (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2151872) and especially at its graphics.